# preg match html to variable php get value span

Tags: javascript, php

**Hello,**

I need to get the value of:

```
<span class="price amount"></span>
```

This is my complete code:

```
<td><div class="yith_wapo_group_final_total"><span id="teste" class="price amount"> VALUE </span></div></td>
```

I need to somehow recover the value that this:

```
<span id = "test" class = "price amount"> VALUE </span>
```

**The goal is to pass the value to a php variable.**

**Thanks.**

Comment: So you are trying to get the value inside the span with id of `teste` ?  Or are you trying to grab the entire span code?

Comment: I just want the value.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$element= $dom->getElementsById('test');

echo $element->nodeValue;
```

Comment: Did not work. =[

Comment: Since an id is always unique, there's no `DOMDocument::getElementsById` method that returns a nodelist, but there's a method `DOMDocument::getElementById` that returns a DOMElement.

Comment: Working ...if doest to load (html) and try print_r($element)

Comment: I edited code try now

Comment: Try it first...

Comment: Did not work. I used your idea, and did it as follows:<?php

$subject = '<td><div class="yith_wapo_group_final_total"><span id="teste" class="price amount">VALUE TEST</span></div></td>';   
 
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($subject);
$element = $dom->getElementById('teste'); 
 
echo $element->nodeValue;

?>

Comment: Thanks my friend.

Comment: I voted to delete your answer since you gave a code without any explanation and because you didn't test it.